# What's the best way to standardize a development environment for a small team?

Tags: development-environment

At work, we (2 other developers and me) develop all of our code on a single internal machine (via network file sharing). This machine runs our development environment (NGINX, Apache, PHP, MySQL, Memcache, Gearman, etc), which is unruly to get installed on a non Linux environment.

We're getting a few more team members (one remote) and I am looking for a better way to manage a common development environment (our developers currently use Windows, Mac, and Linux).

How does your team create a common development platform? A few things I'm thinking about:

- Same setup (a single machine where we write code), but make it external (maybe spin up a cloud server).
- Force everyone to use Linux and replicate the environment on thier development machines.
- Create a virtual machine that replicates the environment and develop inside a VM.

I'm curious what others are doing... Any thoughts on best practices?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, I've used virtual machines (VMWare) and it has worked pretty effectively in creating the same environment for large teams with many developers.

Comment: Assuming your team has somewhat non-archaic machines that can withstand their own load without virtual machines on top of them :D